# Trying to Reconnet issue in Odoo 11.0

Tags: odoo-11

In the case of importing or exporting large amount of data (like 5000 records) from odoo, It show connection lost and trying to reconnect messages. So is there any way to deal with it while working with large amount of records ?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in odoo 12 when I tried to import translation. I did some hard troubleshooting, I disabled nginx that I configured with self signed SSL.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, import records from MSSQL.
Use transient model and pyodbc

```py
import pyodbc
class Import(models.TransientModel):
@api.multi
    def insert_records(self):
        try:
            cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
                'DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=server_address; DATABASE=db_name; UID=uid_name; PWD=pass_word')
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MSSQL_table")
            rows = cursor.fetchall() # or cursor.fetchmany(5000)
            pg_table = self.env["pgSql_table"].search([])
            for row in rows:
                pg_table.create({
                    "pg_colume_name1": row.SQL_colume_name1, ...
                })

        except Exception as e:
            pass
        return True
```

```xml
<button string="import" type="object" name="insert_records" confirm="confirm?"/>
```

Click button to run insert method,and use pyCharm to set break-points while running.
Fetchmany(number) allow you to test few records